# MiniZinc Assign Different Domain to Each Var in Array

Tags: arrays, constraints, constraint-programming, minizinc

I have an array: `array[backpacks] of int: capacity` specifying the capacity of each backpack.

Now I want to create an array of variables which the constraint solver will have to satisfy. I want each variable to take values in domain 1..capacity where capacity corresponds to the one specified in the above array.

Would something like this work: `array[backpacks] of var capacity: bagcaps` ?

Or do I have to do something like: `array[backpacks] of var 1..MAX: bagcaps`

and then add constraints: `constraint forall(i in backpacks) bagcaps[i] <= capacity[i]` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no short cut to restrict the domain of specific element in the array declaration. The traditional version is the one you wrote last:

```
constraint forall(i in backpacks) bagcaps[i] <= capacity[i]);
```

However, you can make this as an predicate (and place it in a separate file which is then imported into the model with `include`). E.g. some thing like this:

```
set of int: backpacks = 1..6;
array[backpacks] of int: capacity = [10,4,3,7,5,3];
array[backpacks] of var 1..max(capacity): bagcaps;

solve satisfy;

predicate restrict_domains(array[int] of var int: x, array[int] of int: d) =
        forall(i in index_set(x)) ( x[i] <= d[i] );

constraint
     % forall(i in backpacks) ( bagcaps[i] <= capacity[i] ) % original
     restrict_domains(bagcaps,capacity)
;

% output [];
```

Note that you must still use `restrict_domains` as a constraint. And I recommend that you always restrict the domain in the declaration as much as possible, i.e. use the declaration using `var 1..max(capacity)` instead of `var int`.